# Lynx how to change blue background color

Tags: lynx

As you can see my lynx's bottom part is hard to read. How can I change the color? I use Solarized Dark on iTerm2.

[image]

Comment: [Lynx Config](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Lynx_Config)

Answer (score 7):

I just fixed this myself:

`sudo vim /etc/lynx-cur/lynx.lss` (.lss in this case stands for Lynx Style Sheet)

This was line #54 for me (about halfway down).

Change

`status:         reverse:                white:          blue`

to

`status:         reverse:                black:          white`

Or whatever you want to change it to. The first value determines font color, the second determines background color.