# Lynx colorscheme reading issue

Tags: colors, lynx

I just start using the text-based Lynx browser, and a part of the interface is very hard to read like you can see on this screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/1003819/362137 which provides an answer:

> sudo vim /etc/lynx-cur/lynx.lss (.lss in this case stands for Lynx
>   Style Sheet)
>
> This was line #54 for me (about halfway down).
>   Change
>
> > status:         reverse:                white:          blue
>
> to
>
> > status:         reverse:                black:          white
>
> Or whatever you want to change it to. The first value determines font
>   color, the second determines background color.

Depending on how you installed lynx, the install location might be different, mine was `~/.linuxbrew/etc/lynx.lss`.

For me also the line was different, the white from the other answer was yellow for me.

Comment: Point taken. I've updated the answer to reflect what is his and what additional information I wanted to add.

Comment: Great. Much better :)